# Getting Internal Attributes of LDAP Object

Tags: java, attributes, ldap, jndi

I am trying to fetch LDAP User internal attributes, but couldn't find how to fetch them

```
DirContext ctx = this.getDirContext();
List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> results = null;
try {
  SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
  controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
  results = ctx.search("", "(objectclass=person)", controls);
  while (results.hasMore()) {
    SearchResult searchResult = results.next();
    Attributes attributes = searchResult.getAttributes();
    String fullName = this.getValue(attributes.get("cn"));
    //so on...
}
// so on
```

from LDAP, I want to fetch each employee/person internal attributes too. 
By Default, it's not returning the internal attributes [ex: createTimestamp]

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You won't get any operational attributes unless you ask for them. At present you aren't asking for any attributes, which is equivalent to constructing the `SearchControls`, or calling `SearchControls.setReturningAttributes(String[])` afterwards, using the argument `new String[]{"*"}:`this gives you all the non-operational attributes.

To get the operational attributes as well, use the argument `new String[]{"*","+"}`.