# Retrieving operational (internal) LDAP attributes via JNDI in one batch

Tags: java, attributes, ldap, jndi

The JNDI `InitialLdapContext` class allows me to retrieve the attributes of an LDAP entry in one line if the Distinguished Name is known:

```
Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes(entryDN);
```

However, this does not include the operational attributes, such as the entryCSN, modifyTimestamp etc. Of course, one can always specify which attributes to get with a string array:

```
Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes(entryDN, new String[] {"entryCSN"});
```

But then only the specified attributes are returned.

Things I have tried, but don't work for me:

1. Retrieving the attributes via `ctx.search()`

   I know I can get all the attributes via search (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18607828/getting-internal-attributes-of-ldap-object)), but I don't want a) to do a whole Ldap query if I already know the dn and b) to deal cumbersomely which the search result set.
2. Doing a second query only for the operational attribute

   Of course I can do just a second query, but I want to save the additional trip and adding the second attributes to first ones like this:

   ```
   Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes(entryDN);
   attributes.put(ctx.getAttributes(entryDN, new String[] {"entryCSN"}).get("entryCSN"));
   ```

   results in a `NoSuchElementException`. Stacktrace:

   ```
   Exception thrown: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Vector Enumeration
   at java.util.Vector$1.nextElement(Vector.java:352)
   at javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute$ValuesEnumImpl.nextElement(BasicAttribute.java:537)
   ```
3. Listing all attributes in the string array

   Since the Ldap entries returned can be different object classes and have therefore different attributes, I see no practical way to do this.

Does anyone know how to get the normal attributes and the operational attributes in one trip?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 magic values for attributes that are defined in LDAP RFCs :
"*" means all user attributes.
"+" means all operational attributes.

The following code should work:

```
Attributes attributes = ctx.getAttributes(entryDN, new String[] {"*", "+"});
```